# DNSSEC resigining shell script struggles

Tags: shell, bind9

I request for help and would appreciate it if someone could help me with my shellscript struggle. The following code is my shellscript to resign the zone-file.

```
#!/bin/bash
hash=$(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16)
command=$(dnssec-signzone -3 $hash –N 'KEEP' –o "owolf.dnssec.local" –t /etc/bind/zones/db.owolf.dnssec.local)
sleep 10
service bind9 reload
```

When i start the script manually it gives me two errors and i can't figure out why.

**First Error:**
!/bin/bash: No such file or directory

I checked it bash is present in the directory /bin.

**Second Error:**
-N Could not open file.

Seems to be an error with the quoting but i already tried ",' and ´ none of them worked.

**What else have i tried?**
I also tried and made sure, that the line endings are converted in unix style, and that there are no other missplaced symbols in the file.

**SOLVED**
The file seems to be broken, created a new file and manually filled in the code. Also fixed some wrong quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
hash=$(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16)
dnssec-signzone -3 "$hash" –N "KEEP" –o "owolf.dnssec.local" –t /etc/bind/zones/db.owolf.dnssec.local
sleep 10
service bind9 reload
```

Comment: but you are using `bash` in your terminal window? Confirm this echo `echo $BASH_VERSION`. Now use `type bash` or `which bash` to see the full path name. Maybe it is stored in `/usr/bin/` or similar? I don't understand why you're storing output into `command=$(...)` , you're not using `$command` in your script. Good luck.

Comment: Try changing first line to `#!/bin/bash -xv`. Try surrounding `$hash` with double quotes. What is `command` for?

Comment: which bash gives me /bin/bash. command was a try to fix the error that occured when i only executed the dnssec-signzone command.
Bash_Version is: 4.3.30(1)-release. With double quotes around $hash and -xv behind /bin/bash -> same exact problem

Comment: What happens if you start lines 2-5 with a hash sign (`#`) and add a new line that says `echo hello`. Does it run then?

Comment: Following output: ./resign.sh: line 1: #!/bin/bash: No such file or directory
hello. whereis bash gives me the path /bin/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file seems to be broken, created a new file and manually filled in the code. Also fixed some wrong quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/cache/bind/ #Key Material is there
hash=$(head -c 1000 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16)
dnssec-signzone -3 "$hash" –N "KEEP" –o "owolf.dnssec.local" –t /etc/bind/zones/db.owolf.dnssec.local
sleep 10
service bind9 reload
```

– lt_katana